# horizontal scroll on android chrome, works in funny way

Tags: horizontal-scrolling, android-browser

in my site I have a responsive table, it is work fine on all browsers on Desktop (windows and Linux), but when I open the page with android chrome (and also ios browser) vertical scroll work just fine, but horizontal is messed up,

- it works on last three rows of my table,
- it doesn't work on upper rows of table
- if I scroll down to see more rows, the problem still exist
- I find one more interesting things, when I'm on the page, and horizontal scroll doesn't work well, and I open the setting of browser and closed it, after this horizontal scroll work fine on all rows.

address of the page:

http://yellowpart.ir/?product_cat=%D8%B4%D8%A7%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D9%BE%D8%A7%DB%8C%DB%8C%D9%86&product_list=149

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of "top" attribute, my table css was:

```
table {
         top: 70vh;
}
```

and it worked fine on pc, but somehow on android chrome, although I did scroll page and table to bottom of it but the table in first 70% of screen's height didn't worked, so I changed the code to :

```
table{
      padding-top: 70vh;
}
```

and it start to work fine on both desktop and android chrome.